# Angularjs data value not loading some times

Tags: angularjs, promise

Am beginner in `angularjs`, I have create `job module` in my project. In this module i did job add and edit.

When i try to `edit` one job details some data's not loading some times. Flowing images are add and edit pages.

**Add Job:**
[image]

**Edit Job:**
[image]

Here Module Items not loading, following codes are am using:

**edit.html:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Module Item<code>*</code></label>

    <select class="form-control" name="moduleitem" ng-model="formData.moduleitem_id" ng-options="moduleitem_id1.id as moduleitem_id1.itemname for moduleitem_id1 in formData.moduleItem" ng-required="true">
    <option value="">Select Module Item</option></select> 
</div>
```

**editjob.js**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('EditJobsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'authServices', '$sessionStorage', 'webServices', 'utility', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$timeout', 'toaster', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $state, authServices, $sessionStorage, webServices, utility, $rootScope, $stateParams, $timeout, toaster, $filter) 
{

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.Id = $stateParams.id;
    $rootScope.loading = true;
    $scope.IMGURL = app.imageurl;
    $scope.validextensions = app.imgextensions;

    $scope.getData = function() {
        webServices.getSync('jobs/' + $scope.Id).then(function(getData) {
            if (getData.status == 200) {
                $scope.formData = getData.data;
console.log($scope.formData);
                $scope.formData.deletedimages = '';
                $scope.display = 0;                
                $rootScope.loading = false;
            } else {
                $rootScope.$emit("showerror", getData);
            }

        });
    }

    $scope.getModuleItem = function() {
        $rootScope.loading = true;
        $scope.loadingMsg = 'Loading';
        webServices.getSync('moduleitem').then(function(getData) {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
            if (getData.status == 200) {
                $scope.formData.moduleItem = getData.data;
            } else {
                $rootScope.$emit("showerror", getData);
            }
        });
    };

}]);
```

In console log i got this

[image]

> Only some times datas not loading.

I dont't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Try to assign $scope.formData.moduleitem_id = $scope.formData.moduleItem.id if the moduleitem_id is undefined

Comment: @KarthickSrinivasan Some times `moduleitem_id ` shows `undefined`. When i clear browser cache `moduleitem_id` values showing.

Comment: well, I noticed that that you are using `$rootScope` which is the most evil thing in Angularjs, make sure you don't have `$rootScope.formData` in your app, otherwise it may cause collisions and lead to unpredictable errors like so

Comment: @LuninRoman: You mean change `$rootScope.loading = false;` to `$rootScope.loading = true;` right?

Comment: @RameshS well, I mean that probably somewhere in your code you placed something in $rootScope.formData, so sometimes it causing problems, anyways, I don't see anything that may cause problems in the code you provided

Comment: @LuninRoman: I find all my js file am not using `$rootScope.formData`. I just using `$rootScope.loading = true/false`

Comment: @LuninRoman Only `drop-down fields` i got this issue.

Comment: @LuninRoman: I search in internet some blogs says use promises and $q to handle asynchronous calls like that how can i use that?

Answer (score 0):

At the time or data binding with html element, check that the variable exists or not with below code:
ng-if="yourVariable"

Comment: Thanks for your answers Pankaj am adding `ng-if="formData.moduleitem_id"` in my `html` code but no result.

Comment: Actually  only `drop-down fields` i got this issue

Comment: make sure you are getting the value in the controller everytime.

Comment: No am not getting every time please check my question console image.

Comment: I search in internet some blogs says use promises and $q to handle asynchronous calls like that how can i use that

Comment: https://medium.com/@alecwazzy/using-promises-to-handle-asynchronous-operations-in-angularjs-83457d983675

Comment: How can i use this am a beginner in angular